# Why can you sometimes cast a NSArray to NSMutableArray, and sometimes you can't?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Specifically:

```
self.words = (NSMutableArray*)[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

works fine so long as there are separators.  I see that the method returns the original string wrapped in an NSArray if there isn't, though.  This single element NSArray stubbornly refuses to be cast as an NSMutableArray.

But, when I do:

```
self.words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.words];
```

It works just fine.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is it bad practice to cast from NSArray to NSMutableArray?

Comment: In Objective-C you can pretty much cast a pointer of any class to a pointer of any other class.  However, just because the compiler allows it and the cast statement itself executes does not mean it's correct.  From the standpoint of arrays, sometimes a pointer to an NSMutableArray is typed as NSArray.  This is perfectly legit, since you can always refer to an object through a superclass pointer.  However, when casting an NSArray to NSMutableArray, the cast is only valid if the object addressed is, in fact, an NSMutableArray.  Casting *does not* change the type of the object.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused.

This code:

```
self.words = (NSMutableArray*)[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

...is wrong, and is setting you up for a crash later on. Casting just tells the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing." It does not change the type of the underlying object. The method componentsSeparatedByString returns an NSArray, not a mutable array. If you then try to mutate the resulting array, you will crash with an unrecognized selector message. With the cast, the compiler trusts you that your object will really be a mutable array at runtime, but it will not be.

This would crash:

```
self.words = (NSMutableArray*)[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
[self.words addObject: @"new"];
```

However, this code:

```
self.words = [[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
[self.words addObject: @"new"];
```

...does the right thing. It doesn't cast a pointer, it is a method call to a method that takes an NSArray as input and returns a mutable array with the same contents. Thus the second line will work because the first line takes the immutable array it gets back from componentsSeparatedByString and uses it to create a mutable array.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to cast from `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`. It may works if you are lucky because the array are constructed using `NSMutableArray`, but you can't rely on it.

If you want `NSMutableArray` from `NSArray`, use `mutableCopy`

```
self.words = [[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it bad practice to cast from NSArray to NSMutableArray?

Yes. Bordering on nonsensical, really.

Typecasting does not change the object in any way at all, it just tells the compiler that it should regard the object as if it were an instance of the new type. At run time though, the object stays exactly the same. You may cast an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray` but it doesn't make the object transform into an `NSMutableArray`. It's still the same object of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Your misconception seems to be about the nature of casting. Casting doesn't *change* the object, it just tells the compiler to *pretend* that it's an object of that type. If the object really isn't an NSMutableArray, casting is not expected to make it become one.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString* string1 = @"this thing";
NSString* string2 = @"this";

NSMutableArray* array1;
NSMutableArray* array2;
array1 = (NSMutableArray*)[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
array2 = (NSMutableArray*)[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

[array1 addObject:string1]; //(A) 
[array2 addObject:string1]; //(B)
```

This will break at (B) the last line with :
        `-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702257a0`

But will *not* break at (A)<sup>1</sup>

An object that is publicly declared as immutable may have been privately created as mutable. In this case, if you cast from the immutable public type to the private mutable type, everything will work fine. Where the object was *not* created as mutable, such a cast will not get you what you want.

In the case of `componentsSerparatedByString`, this suggests that the method implementation creates a mutable array only if it needs to - i.e. if it has to add more than one object to the array. If it only finds one object, you get an NSArray, if it finds more than one, you get an NSMutableArray. This is an implementation detail that is deliberately hidden from you as the user.

The interface tells you to expect an NSArray in all cases, and in all cases this will work.

You should not rely on such details to get you what you want. Stick to the public API, that's what it is for.

<sup>1</sup> rather, as Bryan Chen points out, it may not break now but could well do so in the future

Comment: it _may_ break at (A) in different SDK. maybe a future release

Comment: @BryanChen Quite - that's why we should stick to public APIs.

Answer (score 1):

When you do that:

```
self.words = (NSMutableArray*)[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

the array still remains immutable and if you send it a message from `NSMutableArray` class it will crash. The trick `(NSMutableArray*)` is only good to make the compiler happy.

In the second case:

```
self.words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.words];
```

you do not CAST, you CREATE a new array object.

And of course you don't need to cast the arrays this way. `NSMutableArray` object IS already `NSArray` just like any object of a derived class is an object of a base class at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Use second variant in all cases because it is right solution and more clearly for users who will support your code:

```
NSArray *array = [self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
self.words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Never do this one:

```
self.words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.words];
```

It will totally confuse all devs =)

Comment: @BryanChen, haha =) why? it is standard method from iOS sdk. if it does not make sense why this method is in the SDK then?

Comment: this code by itself is fine but does not do much (make copy of `self.words`). the line before this line can be the problem (assign `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`) and this hides the problem. BTW I never use `arrayWithArray:`. most of the time, it can be replaced with `copy` or `mutableCopy`

Comment: @BryanChen copy and mutableCopy lead to ownership. Is it what you need most of the time? Moreover when you send copy message the elements contained in the array should conform to NSCopying. So may be  arrayWithArray: is easier, don't you think?

Comment: seems it's connected to each developer, but I don't understand how does it add problem. I mean about this solution arrayWithArray?

this method automatically create mutable array and can be used as mutable container. So app can add new amount to this array without problem.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha "follow to ownership"? you mean in non-ARC i need extra `autorelease`? not problem in ARC. also `copy`/`mutableCopy` is shallow copy, its elements _does not_ have to conform to `NSCopying`. read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3)

Comment: @BryanChen can you describe about hidden problem in this case. I agree with that copy and mutableCopy it is great solution, but where is the hidden issue in [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]?

Comment: @BryanChen yes the non-arc this is also one additional thing about we need to think as says AndreyChernukha

Comment: i have no problem with `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]` (except it can be replaced with `mutableCopy`, not big deal). the problem is OP was assign `self.word` to `NSArray` (wrong type, the problem) and re-assign it again hide the problem in previous line. imaging the future maintainer insert some code between these two lines.

Comment: @BryanChen I don't understand what the previous line you mean. I mean only this line of code: self.words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander i won't downvote if this is your answer. but not `self.words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.words];`. see the difference?

Comment: @BryanChen haha =) really. sorry it is copy paste from question issues. I meant another case ))) I have modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method is specifically returning an `NSArray`, which can't just be cast to the mutable type. If you wanted that to be mutable, you would have to do this:

```
self.words = [[self.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
```

The second one is calling the `arrayWithArray:` method on the `NSMutableArray` class, meaning it is making an instance of `NSMutableArray`. That's why it works. You can cast an `NSMutableArray` to an `NSArray`, but not the other way around, because an `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Casting does nothing with an object. example:

```
NSString *mouse = (id)@[@"mouse"];
```

it will compile, but variable mouse is not NSString. it is NSArray. you can check it simply by writing

```
po mouse
```

in console.

The only way to create mutable copy of an object is to call 'mutableCopy' method on it:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"a"];
NSMutableArray *mutableCopy = [array mutableCopy];
```

Comment: it is not "the only way"

Comment: true, but it is the simpliest for shallow copy :p