# Need help understanding a conditional crash when accessing my NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am keeping my data in a property called `practiceRecords` (an `NSArray` of dictionaries).

I check to see if the data already exists in the documents folder.

- If yes, I load the data into `self.practiceRecords`.
- If not, I build the array of dictionaries (using literal syntax), keeping this data in the `self.practiceRecords` property, and then write the data out to the documents folder.
  (*I am **NOT** reloading the data after writing it out*)

As far as I am able to tell, there are no problems occurring during this process.

Then I have a step where I modify my data as follows ...

```
-(void)incNumberOfTriesFor:(NSString *)stringOfIndex {

    if (self.practiceRecords)
    {
        int index = [stringOfIndex intValue];
        int numberOfTries = [(NSNumber *)(self.practiceRecords[index][@"tries"]) intValue] + 1;

        //CRASHING on this next line.
        self.practiceRecords[index][@"tries"] = @(numberOfTries);   

        //message to helper method
        [self writePracticeRecords]; 
    }
}
```

So the first time through (when the array is built and written out) I get a crash at the indicated line.
The error is:

> -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I quit the app, check the documents folder and see the data file written out with no issues.
I re-run the app, and then get no crash and the data file still looks great.
This is repeatable.

- If the data file exists, no crash.
- If the data first needs to be created, then a crash.

(*In all cases, I manually look inside the resulting data file and see exactly what I expect to see - no issues there*)

I'm not sure where to even begin squashing this bug, and would really like to understand the details of why this is happening.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: is it a mutable object or immutable?

Comment: you cannot modify immutable `NSDictionary`. you have to create a `mutableCopy` of it first

Comment: if you had an array of mutable dictionaries _(`NSMutableDictionary`)_ then i suppose your app won't crash first time

Comment: this may explain why it is not always happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006167/why-can-you-sometimes-cast-a-nsarray-to-nsmutablearray-and-sometimes-you-cant/21006233#21006233

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to recap the correct comments above:

> -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

NSDictionary does not implement any of the set... methods because it is immutable.  You state that you're creating with literals syntax when the data is not found on disk.  The literal syntax creates immutable containers

Instead, try...

```
// try to initialize from disk, but if not
// we can still use literal (immutable) syntax, but in a mutable container
self.practiceRecords = [NSMutableDictionary
                           dictionaryWithDictionary:@{ @"key" : @"value" }];
```

Comment: I always do @{...}.mutableCopy

Comment: Thanks, danh.  Making the dictionaries mutable fixed the crash.  I wondered if mutable vs immutable was the issue, but I could not (and still cannot) understand why the crash was conditioned on whether or the not the array of dictionaries had already been created once and written out.

Comment: @dloranz : to know the specific case, you should post code in your question on how you **1.** load `self.practiceRecords` (_if data already exists_) **2.** build `self.practiceRecords` (_if data doesn't already exist_)